# Removing lines with repetitive values in last

Tags: python, perl, bash, awk, bioinformatics

I have a tab delimited file which looks like this

```
chr1  12226559  12227059  TNFRSF1B       
chr1  17051560  17052060                 
chr1  17053279  17053779                 
chr1  17338423  17338923  ATP13A2        
                          ATP13A2        
                          ATP13A2        
chr1  19577574  19578074  EMC1           
                          MRTO4          
chr1  19578046  19578546  EMC1           
                          MRTO4          
chr1  19638239  19638739  AKR7A2         
                          PQLC2          
                          PQLC2          
                          PQLC2
                          AKR7A2         
                          PQLC2
```

I want that the lines where value of column4 is repeated should be removed.

First three columns are co ordinates and in those co-ordinates whatever we find is listed (in col4), and for each co-ordinate I want to have only unique names and not the repeatation of names.

I want an output like this

```
chr1  12226559  12227059  TNFRSF1B       
chr1  17051560  17052060                 
chr1  17053279  17053779                 
chr1  17338423  17338923  ATP13A2              
chr1  19577574  19578074  EMC1           
                          MRTO4          
chr1  19578046  19578546  EMC1           
                          MRTO4          
chr1  19638239  19638739  AKR7A2         
                          PQLC2
```

Things that I have tried

```
sort -k 4 -u file

awk '{if($4==temp1){next;}else{print}temp1=$4}' file
```

Nothing works  :(

Please help

Thank you

Comment: I'm sure your awk script will work if you change the field separator to a tab. Otherwise awk separates words on runs of white space.

Comment: +1 for sample data, required output and attempts at solution. Good luck.

Comment: +1 I spent good time solving your challenge ;-)

Comment: @Angelo @dogbane Consider 3 lines: first one is empty expect `AKR7A2` at the end; the second one is filled `chr1 19638239 19638739 AKR7A2`; and the third one is same as the first one. What is the line that should be kept? From your question requirements, we should keep the first one (the empty one). But my feeling would keep the second one (the filled one). Please give your opinion ;-) Cheers

Comment: Dear all, as suggested by dogbane, I have made edits in the input file. Please try with new input sample file. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need

```
awk '$NF != prev {print} {prev=$NF}'
```

EDIT: to handle the new input

```
awk '{
    if (NF == 1) 
        value = $1
    else {
        key =  $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3
        value = $4
    }
    if ((key SUBSEP value) in val) 
        next
    print
    val[key, value] = 1
}' input
```

Comment: If you're into code golf, you can take advantage of the default action (print): `awk '$NF!=p;{p=$NF}'`

Comment: @ glenn jackman Please have a look at a different input, I did change the input.

Comment: Very good idea, so clean ;-) But when processing two successive lines without fourth column and ending with same third column `17053779`, the second line will be dropped... How to preserve lines not having fourth column? Please provide a second beautiful script to solve that. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '1{x;d};H;x;s/\([ ][^\n ]*\)[ ]*\n[ ]*\1[ ]*\n/\1\n/;$p;x;d;$p;x;d' FILE
```

If you have tabs in your file, apart from spaces, you can replace all `[ ]` with `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: +1 Very good performance have managed this challenge by using only a `sed` script! congratulations ;-)

Comment: I also written a sed interpretor [The semantics is not finished, only syntax], and I will integrate it in gnu/Emacs in future: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2011-05/msg00745.html

Comment: What a pity [I do not use emacs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49203/vim-customized-with-emacs-commands-edition-mode-only) in my new job... I hope your lisp script will be included in an official release... good luck ;-) PS: you still use voila.fr! (please accept my edit in your answer)

Answer (score 1):

Using a tiny `perl` script:

```
perl -e 'my $col4 = "";
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @f = split(/\t/, $_);
  if ($f[3] eq "" || $f[3] ne $col4) {
    print $_, "\n";
  }
  $col4 = $f[3];
}' input.txt
```

result:

```
chr1    12226559        12227059        TNFRSF1B
chr1    17051560        17052060
chr1    17053279        17053779
chr1    17338423        17338923        ATP13A2
chr1    19577574        19578074        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
chr1    19578046        19578546        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
chr1    19638239        19638739        AKR7A2
                                        PQLC2
```

Comment: Please add `\n` in your print, else all the output is printed in a single line. Moreover the `perl` script prints two successive lines ending with `ATP13A2`. Finally the script prints solely the first of successive lines having empty forth column (all should be printed), same drawback as `uniq -f4`. Good luck for corrections...

Comment: +1 Perfect, your script meets the question requirements. However, @dogbane added another requirements => please read from the middle of my answer... cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### simple `awk` script

```
awk -F'\t' '{OFS="\t"; if ($4=="" || $4!=old) print; old=$4}' input.txt
```

### result

```
chr1    12226559        12227059        TNFRSF1B
chr1    17051560        17052060
chr1    17053279        17053779
chr1    17338423        17338923        ATP13A2
chr1    19577574        19578074        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
chr1    19578046        19578546        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
chr1    19638239        19638739        AKR7A2
                                        PQLC2
```

### cleaning

To prepare my `input.txt` file I copied the text from the question. But I had to replace spaces by tabs. Therefore I used a `sed` command. I also noticed some trailing spaces (at the end of the line). Finally, I used the following `sed` command to clean the imput file:

```
sed 's/ *$//;/^[^ ]/s/  */\t/g;/^ /s/  */\t\t\t/g;' copy-fron-so.txt > input.txt
```

### input file from @dogbane comment

```
chr1  12226559  12227059  TNFRSF1B
chr1  17051560  17052060
chr1  17053279  17053779
chr1  17338423  17338923  ATP13A2
                          ATP13A2
                          ATP13A2
chr1  19577574  19578074  EMC1
                          MRTO4
chr1  19578046  19578546  EMC1
                          MRTO4
chr1  19638239  19638739  AKR7A2
                          PQLC2
                          PQLC2
                          PQLC2
                          AKR7A2
```

(the last line have been appended)

### cleaning and processing

```
$> sed 's/ *$//;/^[^ ]/s/  */\t/g;/^ /s/  */\t\t\t/g;' copypaste.txt > input.txt
$> awk -F'\t' '{OFS="\t"; if ($4=="" || $4!=old) print; old=$4}' input.txt
chr1    12226559        12227059        TNFRSF1B
chr1    17051560        17052060
chr1    17053279        17053779
chr1    17338423        17338923        ATP13A2
chr1    19577574        19578074        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
chr1    19578046        19578546        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
chr1    19638239        19638739        AKR7A2
                                        PQLC2
                                        AKR7A2
```

### requirements change

The last line having `AKR7A2` should not be printed. Therefore we need first to sort the `input.txt` file. Caution the option `-t` is for introducing a tab, on `bash` or `vi` press `[CTRL-V]`, then `[TAB]` (put quotes around this tab).

```
$> LANG=C sort -k 4 -s -t ' ' input.txt > sorted.txt 
$> awk -F'\t' '{OFS="\t"; if ($4=="" || $4!=old) print; old=$4}' sorted.txt
chr1    17051560        17052060
chr1    17053279        17053779
chr1    19638239        19638739        AKR7A2
chr1    17338423        17338923        ATP13A2
chr1    19577574        19578074        EMC1
                                        MRTO4
                                        PQLC2
chr1    12226559        12227059        TNFRSF1B
```

Note that there is a single line ending with `MRTO4` now!

Comment: Are sure of this awk command or did you use the correct input. This script with my sample input will not give this output.  :(

Comment: Yes I copy-pasted your input and did some cleaning: removing consecutive spaces, replacing them by tabs, removing trailing spaces... I am appending in my answer what I did to clean the input file...

Comment: Please @Angelo, try my cleaning `sed` script. Maybe there are some nasty spaces within your input file... I have tested my script with the cleaned input file, and it works. Let me know... Cheers

Comment: @olibre With the sample input it works :) I have to check this with a bigger input sample. In principle it should work (+1). I will accept your answer as soon as it gives the desired result with a larger input file (it is processing it). :)

Comment: Hi @dogbane. Forth column does not need to be sorted. Have a look at the result output, there are two lines ending with `MRTO4`. And this is correct as specified in the question example, isn't it?

Comment: @olibre I meant your code assumes that the fourth column is sorted within each "chr1" block. For example, try adding another `AKR7A2` right at the end of the input file. Your script will then print out two `AKR7A2` instead of one.

Comment: Hi @dogbane. The option `-F '\t'` disables the merge of leading tabs when `awk` retrieve the fourth column. For instance, in the input file of the question, there are three consecutive lines having `ATP13A2` as fourth field: the last two lines do not have `chr1` and they are not displayed... Maybe I did not understand what you mean... I am appending into my answer another line having just `AKR7A2` as fourth column, and please tell me if is that you want I check... see you soon

Comment: Hi @olibre, Yes, that's exactly what I mean. If you look at your final output you will see that there are two `AKR7A2`, but there should only be one.

Comment: @dogbane Well this changes a lot the specification requirements... Do both lines having `MRTO4` have to be printed? Or just one?

Comment: @Olibre : For each co-ordinate the names need to be sorted and redundants in that co-ordinates need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($col3) = (split)[-1];
    print if !$seen{$col3}++ or !$col3;
}

__DATA__
chr1    12226559    12227059    TNFRSF1B
chr1    17051560    17052060    
chr1    17053279    17053779    
chr1    17338423    17338923    ATP13A2
                                ATP13A2
                                ATP13A2
chr1    19577574    19578074    EMC1
                                MRTO4
chr1    19578046    19578546    EMC1
                                MRTO4
chr1    19638239    19638739    AKR7A2
                                PQLC2
                                PQLC2
                                PQLC2
```

Output:

```
chr1    12226559    12227059    TNFRSF1B
chr1    17051560    17052060    
chr1    17053279    17053779    
chr1    17338423    17338923    ATP13A2
chr1    19577574    19578074    EMC1
                                MRTO4
chr1    19638239    19638739    AKR7A2
                                PQLC2
```

This output can also be achieved with the following one-liner:

```
perl -ane "print if !$X{$F[-1]}++ or !$F[-1]" data.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Kenosis I did not reach to test your `perl` scripts. I use `perl` v5.8.8. On first script, I have this output: `Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at -e line 6.\n
readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at -e line 6.`. On the second tiny script, this output: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "++ or"\n
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`. Please can you give more information how to solve that? Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Given the newly posted input I'd use:

```
gawk -F'\t' '!/^\t/{delete a} !a[$4]++' file
```

I use gawk so I can clearly delete the whole array at one time, with other awks use the less clear:

```
awk -F'\t' '!/^\t/{split("",a)} !a[$4]++' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the repeated lines are duplicated in *all* columns and not just the fourth, uniq(1) is probably suitable. Try running just `uniq file` and see if the output is what you expect.

Comment: Well I want the command to look for repetition in only a segment like repetition in this segment chr1 17338423 17338923 ATP13A2 ATP13A2 ATP13A2